# php fetching no data with prepared statement without any placeholder

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am in prototype stage with my site.
Since prepared statements are more secure & the new way to talk with mysql db, I decided to use them and read the related sections in php.net but all examples in php.net are given with placeholders like `where name = ?`. 
Below I need no placeholder I suppose but I couldn't achieve printing my output. 
I have no output from my db.
**I have notices that are:**
Notice: Undefined variable: row in ... on line 16
Notice: Undefined variable: row in ... on line 16
Notice: Undefined variable: row in ... on line 16
Notice: Undefined variable: row in ... on line 16

What should I do? Can you help me please. 
Thank you, regards
**in my index.php**

```
//mysql bağlantısı
    global $db_baglanti;
    $db_baglanti = new mysqli(vt_host, vt_user, vt_password, vt_name);
    if ($db_baglanti->connect_errno) 
    {
        echo "MySQL bağlantısı kurulamadı: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    if (!$db_baglanti->set_charset("utf8")) 
    {
        printf("utf8 karakter setinin yüklenmesinde problem oluştu: %s\n", $db_baglanti->error);
    } 
    else 
    {
        $db_baglanti->set_charset("utf8");
    }
```

**in an included page**

```
$sorgum = "SELECT kolon_baslik, kolon_yazi FROM tb_yazilar";


if ($beyan = $db_baglanti->prepare($sorgum)) 
{

    /* execute statement */
    $beyan->execute();



    /* fetch values */
    while ($beyan->fetch()) {
        echo $row['kolon_baslik'].'<br /><br />'.$row['kolon_yazi'].'<br /><br />';
    }

    /* close statement */
    $beyan->close();
}
```

Comment: This [PHP error reference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/367456) might be of help for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the almighty manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

> Note that all columns must be bound by the application before calling
>   mysqli_stmt_fetch().

and from the first example:

```php
/* execute statement */
$stmt->execute();

/* bind result variables */
$stmt->bind_result($name, $code);

/* fetch values */
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $name, $code);
}
```

What you are missing is `$beyan->bind_result($kolon_baslik, $kolon_yazi);` and use these variables instead of nonexistent `$row` array.

Answer (score 0):

thanks, I found answer at this link: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php.
Working code is:

```
if ($beyan = $db_baglanti->prepare($sorgum)) 
{

    /* execute statement */
    $beyan->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $beyan->bind_result($name, $code);

    /* fetch values */
    while ($beyan->fetch()) {
        //printf ("%s (%s)\n", $name, $code)
        echo $name.'<br /><br />'.$code.'<br /><br />';
    }

    /* close statement */
    $beyan->close();
}
```

I learnt that I have to bind mysql results to variables and then I print that binded variables values. related code is: `$beyan->bind_result($name, $code);`